# NUnit [Test] is not a valid attribute

Tags: .net, unit-testing, tdd, nunit

I've included the necessary assemblies into a Windows Class project in VS2008. When I start to try to write a test I get a red squiggle line and the message [Test] is not a valid attribute. I've used NUnit before... maybe an earlier version. What am I doing wrong? I'm on version 2.5.2.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NUnit;
using NUnit.Core;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class LoginTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void CanLogin()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you referenced the assemblies in the project?

Comment: try to compile and paste the first error message

Comment: On a side note, the only namespace you need is nunit.framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the extra `using` lines getting you in trouble. Only use `using NUnit.Framework;`

Internally NUnit.Core also has a type named `Test` and you are colliding with that.

Altenatively you could use `[TestAttribute]` fully spelling out the Attribute part resolves the collision.

Comment: Thanks a combo of this ... and dropping and adding my references seemed to resolve the issue.

Comment: @tyndall - glad it helped. Sorry, I should have been more explicit about dropping the reference to NUnit.Core. You shouldn't need it for normal test writing.

Comment: I have the same error message but this solution doesn't work. It is interesting I'm getting  red squiggle line on all keywords such as Test, Assert, TestFixture and ...

Comment: @amitkohan - Are you sure you referenced the NUnit dlls? It has been a long time since I worked in .NET, but I don't think the structure of NUnit changed that much.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem to this using version 2.5.3.
The problem was that I was looking for the dll files in the "lib" directory of my nunit installation when I should have been looking in the "framework" directory.
So when I referenced the "framework\nunit.framework.dll" dll everything worked.
Hope this helps

Comment: This answer was spot on for my part - referencing from the framework dir solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the [TestFixture] attribute on top of your class, also, you only need to include the following usings for NUnit: using NUnit.Framework;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class LoginTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void CanLogin()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree. [TestFixture] won't allow me to use it without parameters. Never seen that before. But I think I read somewhere that it was no longer needed for simple test classes. But I can't figure out the [Test] problem.